# minimum transfer speed a connection is allowed to have

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx and wonder what server settings are you using to set minimum transfer speed a connection is allowed to have?

Keep looking to a few things like setting up a minimum incoming data rate to drop connections that are too slow.

Any ideas much appreciated.